# Are Word 2000 dictionaries compatible with later versions of Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2000

I have a French version of Microsoft Word 2000 on my computer. If I install a later version of Word (for example 2016) in Swedish without uninstalling Word 2000, will both versions of Word be able to correct spelling in both languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the MS Word versions are installed in the different directories so they can't "see" each other. Nevertheless you can add the dictionary from an old version (MS Word 2000) to the current one as a custom dictionary, take a look: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322198
Try it this way, it should work.